# SVD of “almost” block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, block-matrices

It is possible to show that SVD of block diagonal matrix is equivalent to independent SVDs of each block. I am wondering if there is something interesting to say on the case where the matrix is composed of 2 blocks of size $N$, with $k$ rows and $k$ columns of size $2N+k$ (overlapping in a $k\times k$ corner) added on. I am particularly interested in the influence of the “shared” rows on the reconstruction of the entire matrix when using truncated SVD.

An example:

\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{matrix}
  X_1
  \end{matrix}
  & 0 & \vdots \\
\
  0& X_2 & \vec{u} \\ 
\cdots & \vec{v} &\vdots
\end{pmatrix}

Here, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the two diagonal blocks; each block is $N \times N$. I concatenate to them a single row $\vec{v}$ with $2N+1$ entries and a single column $\vec{u}$ with $2N+1$ entries, and aim to understand how the SVD of the complete matrix relates to the SVD of the block diagonal sub-matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Shared/dense here mean having nonzero entries potentially on all 2N columns, as opposed to the block-diagonal rows which have nonzero entries only within their corresponding blocks (maximum of N nonzeros).

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to understand what you mean by "$N+k$ dense rows of size $2N$". Could you explain a bit more or give an example?

Comment: I added an example, I hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I edited a bit more, check if you agree. Now I think I understand what you are asking. (Still don't know if there is any useful relation of the kind you are asking for, though. Seems challenging).

Comment: I believe that the matrices you're describing are called block arrowhead matrices.

Comment: Cauchy's interlacing theorem for singular values gives inequalities. The discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382142/interlacing-theorem-on-singular-values) explains why the interlacing inequality holds for singular values.