# How do the singular values of a Hankel matrix, generated by some data time series, change when we add/remove rows and columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, time-series, singular-values, hankel-matrices

Suppose I have a smooth time series $C(t)$ defined on the interval $t=[0,T]$, from which I extract the sub-series $c=\{x_1,\cdots,x_N\}$ of $N$ entries, where $x_i=C(i*T/N)$. Naturally, the number $N$ defines the sampling frequency, and in the limit of $N\to\infty$ we recover the full signal with infinite detail. I can turn this series $c$ into a Hankel matrix

$H_c=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2& \cdots& x_N\\
x_2&x_3&\cdots&x_1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
x_N&x_1&\cdots&x_{N-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

I need to perform a singular value decomposition (SVD) on this Hankel matrix for different values of the sampling frequency, usually powers of 2. My question is, how do the singular values change when you go from $N=16$ to $N=32$ for example? Does there exist a clear-cut relation dependent on $C(t)$? Or do there exist lower/upper bounds on the new singular values $\sigma_k$?

I have attempted some proofs but I quickly found out I do not have the appropriate tools in my toolbox to tackle this problem fully. I also did some numerical simulations of easy series, like $c=\{0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\}\to c=\{0,\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{8},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8}\}$ to see if there was any correlation between the singular values but failed to find a consistent pattern.

Comment: One thing that can be said is that the singular values for $N = 16$ will "interlace" those for $N = 32$. This can be seen by combining the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) with the ideas [presented here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1382142/81360).

Comment: You might also be interested in the [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Properties) for the eigenvalues of $H_c$ in terms of the series using the fact that your Hankel matrix is also circulant. Because $H_c$ is circulant, it is normal (i.e. satisfies $H_c^TH_c = H_cH_c^T$), which means that its singular values are simply the absolute values of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I still don't see, though, how the singular value interlace those of higher order matrices. This is because while the eigenvalues do interlace, the singular values are the absolute values of those eigenvalues which renders the $\alpha_j \leq \beta_j \leq \alpha_{n-m+j}$ inequality incorrect.